# Method to export iphone local music files and playlists from iphone to windows

Tags: windows, ios, iphone-app

I lost access to the computer were I have itunes, my music and playlists backed up. Is there a Way yo export playlists from iphone to windows?
Preferably one playlist per directory?
I can export all music via 3Utoos, but then it lost the playlist information.
Thank tou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method to export iphone local music files and playlists from iphone to windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88820/method-to-export-iphone-local-music-files-and-playlists-from-iphone-to-windows)